# Discord bot can join voice channels but doesn't make sounds (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I am writing a bot for my server and decided to add a music system. Since youtube-dl was blocked I decided to use wavelink. I do not know much about it and therefore could make mistakes in the code, but still to the topic. In the console there are no errors, the bot when entering the command play sees the request and can enter the voice channel, but nothing turns on and in general near it does not appear a green circle. Help please.

```
import discord
import wavelink
from discord.ext import commands


class Bot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True, presences=True)
        intents.message_content = True

        super().__init__(intents=intents, command_prefix='!')

    async def on_ready(self) -> None:
        print(f'Logged in {self.user} | {self.user.id}')

    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        # Wavelink 2.0 has made connecting Nodes easier... Simply create each Node
        # and pass it to NodePool.connect with the client/bot.
        node: wavelink.Node = wavelink.Node(uri='https://lava1.horizxon.tech:443', password='horizxon.tech', secure=True)
        await wavelink.NodePool.connect(client=self, nodes=[node])


bot = Bot()
levels = {}

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx: commands.Context, *, search: str) -> None:
    """Простая команда воспроизведения."""

    if not ctx.voice_client:
        vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client

    tracks = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(search)
    if not tracks:
        await ctx.send(f'Сори броу, я не нашёл этого трека: `{search}`')
        return

    track = tracks[0]
    await vc.play(track)
    await ctx.send(f"Сейчас играет: ***{track}***")

@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx: commands.Context) -> None:
    """Simple disconnect command.

    This command assumes there is a currently connected Player.
    """
    vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
    await vc.disconnect()
    await ctx.send(f"стоп")
```

I tried to change the code and make a new one based on FFmpeg to test the sound in the bot, but the bot joins and exits without making any sound when joining the command

Comment: I haven't used `wavelink` before, so if you don't have to use it, I can try changing the code to use yt_dlp instead. would you like that?

Comment: You have posted your wavelink Node and its password, I would recommend changing your password before anyone uses it.

Comment: @kytpbs1 I was originally planning to use it too, but if I'm not mistaken they got sued and stopped working on it. https://yt-dl.org. If I am wrong and it can still be used, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @kytpbs1 this host and password is publicly available on one of the first sites